# Router with bandwidth control to switch

Tags: router, bandwidth, switch

If i limit the bandwidth in a router like only 2Mbps and i connect a switch, does all devices connected to a switch will have 2Mbps bandwidth, or all devices will share in 2Mbps bandwidth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your setup every device would share the 2Mbit/s connection to the router, **but** the connection between the devices may be faster, for example you have an 100Mbit/s switch, then every connected device (except the router) could communicate with any other device connected to the switch with the full 100Mbit/s.

Be aware, that limiting the port to 2Mbit/s will not give actually an 2Mbit/s connection to the router, you have to subtract overhead, collissions etc.

Comment: thank you, i got the answer, its just my question is wrong because english is not my  native language, the switch is the one connected in router i mean, but as you said that every device connected in router will share in 2Mbps, then all devices that connected to switch which is connected to router will share in 2Mbps given by router